# Important differences for the hydration free energy of dioxygen in the literature

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to find a reliable source for the value of $\Delta G^{\circ}_{solv}$ of $O_2$ in $\ce{H_2O}$ at $T = 298.15 K$ to compare with my DFT calculation.

I get $\Delta G^{\circ}_{solv} = 6.33 \text{ kcal/mol} $ from: Abraham, Michael H. Journal of the American Chemical Society, vol. 104, no. 8, Apr. 1982, pp. 2085–94. https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00372a001

More recently, you can find $\Delta G^{\circ}_{solv} =  3.96 \text{ kcal/mol}$ from: Plyasunov, Andrey V., and Everett L. Shock. Geochimica et Cosmochimica Acta, vol. 67, no. 24, Dec. 2003, pp. 4981–5009, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gca.2003.08.003

The chemistry handbook (95th edition, 2015) only gives enthalpy of hydrations of gases, $\Delta H^{\circ}_{solv} = -0.29 \text{ kcal/mol}$ but still very different from the first source which gives $\Delta H^{\circ}_{solv} = -2.88 \text{ kcal/mol}$

The standard state for the first source is 1 atm, the second 0.1 MPa, which I think is pretty close. Why such big difference?

Comment: Instead of writing `$H_2O$` to get  $H_2O$, write `$\ce{H2O}$` to get $\ce{H2O}$. Ch. formulas are written upright. // You may find useful these links for text and formula formatting (not to be applied to titles):
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: For what it's worth, if I calculate based on the Keq derived from reported values of the Henry's law constant, I get something close to the 3.96 kcal/mol value. The Henry's Law constant values given in the wikipedia article on Henry's Law are consistent with the higher end of the solubility values I've found for O2 in H2O at 298 K, which seem to cluster between 1.2 and 1.3 mmol/L